# Positioned 3 different divs

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have 3 different divs in html file.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.second {
  background: red;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
}

.third {
  background: green;
  top: 400px;
  left: 400px;
}

.first {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

I want to move one div.Anyone I want.But when I move any divs this must effect others.Example:When I added margin to .second div this divs change position in page flow.I want this effects to .first and .third div.How can I do it?

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

Comment: what do you want ?? all div in one line display ?

Comment: plz briefly what do you want. then i can help

Comment: ** when adding margin .second div its change his position in page flow.I want  when .second change his position .first and .third change his position same time**

Comment: @SahilSahilov do you want the 1st and 3rd bos to stay on the same line and move the 2nd box below (like in a chess board). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @SubashMatheswaran I add margin second div.When I add margin second div this will change position.I want same event effects to first and third div

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpkfyyqx1m8x7cj/div-position.png?dl=0       In this link picture I show what I want

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of CSS `position:absolute` is to remove the element from the document flow so that changing the margins or size won't effect other elements around it.

If you want your `<div>`s to be affected by margins of other divs, instead of using `position:absolute` try using `float:left` (or [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a more powerful solution).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `position: absolute` let it be `relative`

Have a look at the [CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJNevX) if this solves your problem

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  /*   position: absolute; */
}

.second {
  background: red;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.third {
  background: green;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

.first {
  background: yellow;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to add a margin on all three divs?

We can do that by putting them inside a container.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

And adding the margin to the `container` class.

```
.container {
  margin: 10px
}
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pcyq20vx/

Comment: no.this will move this but I want add margin .second div and move three divs same time

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, the task is: Changing the position of `first`, `second`, and `third` by adding `margin` **exclusively** to `second`?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpkfyyqx1m8x7cj/div-position.png?dl=0       In this link picture I show what I want

Comment: Okay, thanks for drawing the expected output. I at least got the output right. Are we allowed to change the HTML? (example: adding a container)